# How can I change li color when the navbar become sticky?

Tags: javascript, css, navbar, sticky

I would like to change the color of links on my Navbar when the position becomes sticky.  ("links-color") is a css class to replace the existing classes on li's.

The code for Sticky position is working already.

```
var customNav = document.querySelector(".navbarcontainer");
var mylinks = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-link");
var CustomSticky = customNav.offsetTop;

function myNav() {
  console.log("CustomSticy= " + CustomSticky);
  console.log("scrollY=" + window.scrollY);

  if (window.scrollY >= CustomSticky) {
    customNav.classList.add("sticky-navbar");
    mylinks.classlist.add("links-color")
  } else {
    customNav.classList.remove("sticky-navbar ");
    mylinks.classlist.remove("links-color")
  }
}
window.addEventListener('scroll', myNav);
```

Comment: Please provide us with a minimum reproducible example.
You can use e.g. JSFiddle to show us your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

if your dom elements are aligned -- 
`.navbarcontainer.sticky-navbar -> ul -> li -> a.link-color`

then
`.sticky-navbar li{ color: red }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $header = $('header');
    var $sticky = $header.before($header.clone().addClass("sticky"));
    $(window).on("scroll", function(){
        var scrollFromTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        $("body").toggleClass("scroll", (scrollFromTop > 100));
    });



header.sticky  ul li a {
    color: red;
}
body.scroll header.sticky {
    transform: translateY(0);
}
header.sticky {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.85);
       z-index: 5;
}


<header>
      <nav class="nav-wrapper">
        <div class="logo">
          <a href="#">
            logo
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#work">My Work</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>

        </ul>
      </nav>
          </header>
```